# Why memory is not being freed?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am trying to fix a memory leak in C++, I am relatively new to C++ so maybe is a stupid thing. I have some code which takes a screen capture and I am allocating some memory for the Image I will then manipulate. Here is some relevant code:

```
RGBTRIPLE* ScreenShot(char *BmpName, DWORD &height, DWORD &width, char* bmpToFree){
    DWORD FileSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)+1 * (Width*Height * 4));
    char *BmpFileData = (char*)GlobalAlloc(0x0040, FileSize);

    // Some code

    BitBlt(CaptureDC, 0, 0, Width, Height, DevC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
    GetDIBits(CaptureDC, CaptureBitmap, 0, Height, Image, (LPBITMAPINFO)BInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    height = Height;
    width = Width;
    bmpToFree = BmpFileData;

    DeleteObject(CaptureBitmap);
    DeleteObject(CaptureDC);
}
```

As you can see I am not freeing BmpFileData with `GlobalFree(BmpFileData)` because I still need to work with this data in another method so I keep a reference passing the pointer to another pointer in this line `bmpToFree = BmpFileData;`

So now I do some work with this data and then I use `GlobalFree()` on this way:

```
char* bmpToFree = NULL;

RGBTRIPLE *image = ScreenShot("Prueba.bmp", h, w, bmpToFree);
// Do some work
GlobalFree(bmpToFree);
```

But on this way I am having a memory leak. If I instead put `GlobalFree(BmpFileData)` inside `Screenshot()` method my leak is gone but I don't have the data to work on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak?

Comment: When I start the program in a few minutes it uses almost all of my 8Gb of RAM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `bmpToFree` should be a reference to a pointer.

```
RGBTRIPLE* ScreenShot(.., char* bmpToFree)
```

should be

```
RGBTRIPLE* ScreenShot(.., char* &bmpToFree)
```

Or you can work it out another way.

```
RGBTRIPLE* ScreenShot(.., char** bmpToFree)
{
   ...
   *bmpToFree = BmpFileData;
}
```

They are basically the same, either reference(`&`) to the variable(`char *`), or the pointer(`*`) to the variable(`char *`). You use them when you need change the original variable passed in instead of the copy.

Comment: Just... wow, so simple! What is the difference? I know references are like pointers but you can't change what they are pointing to. Never heard of reference to a pointer!

Comment: A reference is essentially a pointer to a variable internally. It's copy by reference instead of copy by value. When you change the reference, you change the original object instead of the copy. In your case, you need change the outside variable which happens to be a pointer itself storing the address you want free later.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the value of the pointer to the function - but when it returns, the original value is not updated.  You need to pass a reference to the pointer - so that the statement inside the function

```
 bmpToFree = BmpFileData;
```

Actually updates the variable in the calling routine.  You can do this by passing the address of the pointer, that is

```
&bmpToFree
```

To make this work you need to change the function signature to expect a pointer-to-a-pointer

```
RGBTRIPLE* RGBTRIPLE* ScreenShot(char *BmpName, DWORD &height, DWORD &width, char** bmpToFree);

inside the function, you change the line to

 *bmpToFree = BmpFileData;
```

And you call it with

```
RGBTRIPLE *image = ScreenShot("Prueba.bmp", h, w, &bmpToFree);
```

Answer (score 2):

as far as i can see, the function should be declared like:

```
RGBTRIPLE* ScreenShot(char *BmpName, DWORD &height, DWORD &width, char*& bmpToFree)
```

otherwise, the assignment to the pointer is just to a local copy of your bmpToFree, it will not remain after function returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function to modify an argument, the argument must be passed by reference, not by value. You can use either a pointer or a reference, but preferably a reference.

For example:

```
void add(int a, int b, int& result) {
   result = a + b;
}
```

(Obviously you would use a return value in real life, but this is just an example.)

or

```
void add(int a, int b, int* result) {
   *result = a + b;
}
```

NOT this:

```
void add(int a, int b, int result) {
   result = a + b; // Only local copy of result is modified
}
```

So, in your case, you're trying to modify the value of an argument that is a pointer. You therefore need to pass this argument by reference, i.e. char*& bmpToFree